# ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) - Scss files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm running a Rails (v4.2.6) application. When I try to use `.scss`, the application crashes when using Sass functionality (i.e.: using variables).

The exact error it gives:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (in .../app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
```

on line

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

**Code causing crash** in `application.scss` (using a variable)

```
    $color: #FFF;
    a {
      color: $color;
    }
```

**Gemfile**

```
    # encoding: UTF-8
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails'

    # Use mysql as the production database
    gem 'mysql2'

    # authentication gems
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'doorkeeper'

    # logging
    gem 'impressionist'

    # RestClient for sending mail using mailgun
    gem 'rest-client'

    # new search engine
    gem 'fuzzily'

    # Use SCSS for stylesheets, sprockets for assets
    gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.11.0'
    gem 'sass-rails'

    # use of Haml and rabl
    gem 'haml'
    gem 'rabl'

    # Gem voor html5 stubs met form features
    gem 'modernizr-rails'

    # Use for javascript and libraries
    gem 'execjs'
    gem 'jquery-rails'

    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'responders'

    # settings cached in rails environment
    gem 'rails-settings-cached'

    # Paperclip easy file upload to S3
    gem 'paperclip'

    # fancy JS alert and confirm
    gem 'sweetalert-rails'

    # Clipboard: Saved text to clipboard
    gem 'clipboard-rails'

    group :production do
      gem 'unicorn'
      gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.5.7'
      gem 'uglifier'
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'web-console'
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'faker'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'faker'
    end
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
    GEM
      remote: https://rubygems.org/
      specs:
        actionmailer (4.2.6)
          actionpack (= 4.2.6)
          actionview (= 4.2.6)
          activejob (= 4.2.6)
          mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
        actionpack (4.2.6)
          actionview (= 4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          rack (~> 1.6)
          rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
          rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
        actionview (4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          builder (~> 3.1)
          erubis (~> 2.7.0)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
          rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
        activejob (4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          globalid (>= 0.3.0)
        activemodel (4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          builder (~> 3.1)
        activerecord (4.2.6)
          activemodel (= 4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          arel (~> 6.0)
        activesupport (4.2.6)
          i18n (~> 0.7)
          json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
          minitest (~> 5.1)
          thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
          tzinfo (~> 1.1)
        arel (6.0.3)
        aws-sdk (1.5.8)
          httparty (~> 0.7)
          json (~> 1.4)
          nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
          uuidtools (~> 2.1)
        bcrypt (3.1.11)
        builder (3.2.2)
        climate_control (0.0.3)
          activesupport (>= 3.0)
        clipboard-rails (1.6.0)
        cocaine (0.5.8)
          climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
        coffee-rails (4.1.1)
          coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
          railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
        coffee-script (2.4.1)
          coffee-script-source
          execjs
        coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
        debug_inspector (0.0.2)
        devise (3.5.6)
          bcrypt (~> 3.0)
          orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
          railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
          responders
          thread_safe (~> 0.1)
          warden (~> 1.2.3)
        domain_name (0.5.20160310)
          unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
        doorkeeper (3.1.0)
          railties (>= 3.2)
        erubis (2.7.0)
        execjs (2.6.0)
        faker (1.6.3)
          i18n (~> 0.5)
        fuzzily (0.3.3)
          activerecord (>= 2.3.17)
        globalid (0.3.6)
          activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
        haml (4.0.7)
          tilt
        hike (1.2.3)
        http-cookie (1.0.2)
          domain_name (~> 0.5)
        httparty (0.13.7)
          json (~> 1.8)
          multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
        httpclient (2.7.1)
        i18n (0.7.0)
        impressionist (1.5.1)
          httpclient (~> 2.2)
          nokogiri (~> 1.5)
        jquery-rails (4.1.1)
          rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
          railties (>= 4.2.0)
          thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
        json (1.8.3)
        kgio (2.10.0)
        loofah (2.0.3)
          nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
        mail (2.6.4)
          mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
        mime-types (2.99.1)
        mimemagic (0.3.0)
        mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
        minitest (5.8.4)
        modernizr-rails (2.7.1)
        multi_json (1.11.2)
        multi_xml (0.5.5)
        mysql2 (0.4.3)
        netrc (0.11.0)
        nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
          mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
        orm_adapter (0.5.0)
        paperclip (4.3.6)
          activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
          cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
          mime-types
          mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
        rabl (0.12.0)
          activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
        rack (1.6.4)
        rack-test (0.6.3)
          rack (>= 1.0)
        rails (4.2.6)
          actionmailer (= 4.2.6)
          actionpack (= 4.2.6)
          actionview (= 4.2.6)
          activejob (= 4.2.6)
          activemodel (= 4.2.6)
          activerecord (= 4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
          railties (= 4.2.6)
          sprockets-rails
        rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
        rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
          nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
          rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
        rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
          loofah (~> 2.0)
        rails-settings-cached (0.5.4)
          rails (>= 4.2.0)
        railties (4.2.6)
          actionpack (= 4.2.6)
          activesupport (= 4.2.6)
          rake (>= 0.8.7)
          thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
        raindrops (0.16.0)
        rake (11.1.2)
        responders (2.1.2)
          railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
        rest-client (1.8.0)
          http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
          mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
          netrc (~> 0.7)
        sass (3.4.21)
        sass-rails (5.0.4)
          railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
          sass (~> 3.1)
          sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
          sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
          tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
        spring (1.6.4)
        sprockets (2.11.3)
          hike (~> 1.2)
          multi_json (~> 1.0)
          rack (~> 1.0)
          tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
        sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
          actionpack (>= 3.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0)
          sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
        sweetalert-rails (1.1.3)
          railties (>= 3.1.0)
        thor (0.19.1)
        thread_safe (0.3.5)
        tilt (1.4.1)
        turbolinks (2.5.3)
          coffee-rails
        tzinfo (1.2.2)
          thread_safe (~> 0.1)
        uglifier (3.0.0)
          execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
        unf (0.1.4)
          unf_ext
        unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
        unicorn (5.0.1)
          kgio (~> 2.6)
          rack
          raindrops (~> 0.7)
        uuidtools (2.1.5)
        warden (1.2.6)
          rack (>= 1.0)
        web-console (3.1.1)
          activemodel (>= 4.2)
          debug_inspector
          railties (>= 4.2)

    PLATFORMS
      ruby

    DEPENDENCIES
      aws-sdk (~> 1.5.7)
      clipboard-rails
      devise
      doorkeeper
      execjs
      faker
      fuzzily
      haml
      impressionist
      jquery-rails
      modernizr-rails
      mysql2
      paperclip
      rabl
      rails
      rails-settings-cached
      responders
      rest-client
      sass-rails
      spring
      sprockets (~> 2.11.0)
      sweetalert-rails
      turbolinks
      uglifier
      unicorn
      web-console

    BUNDLED WITH
       1.13.6
```

**Notes**

I have seen that the `require` statements are not recommended when using sass-rails, but removing these statements does not help

Using `sass application.scss application.css` outputs a valid `css` file

Edit (22/03/17):
Fixed spaces in code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces before the colons like this:

```
$color: #FFF;
a {
  color: $color;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. I should note that `sass application.scss application.css` outputs a valid `css` file